# Windows Registry Run Key

Tags: windows, command-line, registry, startup

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx:

*"Run and RunOnce registry keys cause programs to run each time that a user logs on. The data value for a key is a command line."*

Should I then be able to add a key with:

- Name: MyName
- Data: `START /MIN "Title" "cmd.exe" /c "@echo off && "C:\TestApplication.exe" -Arg1 "Arg2"`

with the goal being to start my console application `"C:\TestApplication.exe"` minimized with arguments `"-Arg1 "Arg2""` when Windows starts?

I ask because I cannot seem to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is misleading, though not strictly incorrect.  The command line is passed directly to CreateProcess() rather than being passed to `cmd.exe` so commands internal to `cmd.exe`, such as `start`, are not valid.  This means you need to add `cmd /c` at the start of the command line.

You're also missing a quote mark at the end, and you don't need to put quotes around `cmd.exe`.  This works:

```
cmd /c START /MIN "Title" cmd /c "@echo off && "C:\TestApp.exe" -Arg1 "Arg2""
```

However, since the target application is an executable, not a batch file, you don't need the `@echo` command either:

```
cmd /c START /MIN "Title" cmd /c ""C:\TestApp.exe" -Arg1 "Arg2""
```

(Note that the command line passed to `/c` is never echoed.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this results in a command prompt popping up for a split second which I need to avoid. But from how you describe the way this system works, I would assume starting an application minimized from the registry directly is not possible.

Comment: Not directly, but it would be trivial to write a GUI application to do so, and reference that in the Run key.